# Добавление класса по клику + проверка на наличие класса и добавление класса другому div

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня немного запутанное задание:
нужно чтобы при клике на `input.input-checkbox` другому `div.tr` добавлялся класс `checked`, при этом еще одному диву нужно присваивать `class="fixed"`, если у другого есть `class="checked"`

Я тут наворотила по моему, но первый скрипт работает правильно и нормально... а вот с добавлением `.fixed` что- то туплю

Структура примерно такая

```js
$("input.input-checkbox").click(function() {
  var par = $(this).parent("div");
  if (par.hasClass("checked"))
    par.removeClass("checked");
  else
    par.addClass("checked");
});



if ($('.tr').hasClass('checked')) {
  $('.finish')
    .addClass('fixed');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tr"><input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="tr"><input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="tr"><input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="finish"></div>
```

Comment: А второй скрипт у Вас собственно при каких условиях должен срабатывать? Т.е. первый у Вас срабатывает при `$("input.input-checkbox").click...` А вот для второго IF у Вас ничего не прописано, т.е. система просто не использует этот кусок кода.

Comment: я не знаток js, поэтому почему то думала что этого хватит $('.tr').hasClass('checked')

Comment: Нет, Вам нужно событие, с которым связанно выполнение кода. Если покажите больше кода + скажите что когда должно происходить - думаю получите ответ.

Comment: добавила пример кода в вопрос

Comment: если вам нужно чтобы div.finish получал класс fixed при условии что хоть один div.tr имеет .checked то вот так: if($("div.tr.checked").length>0){$(".finish").addClass("fixed")}

Comment: или скорее так if($("div.tr").find(".checked").length>0){$(".finish").addClass("fixed")}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("input.input-checkbox").click(function(){
var par = $(this).parent("div");
if (par.hasClass("checked"))
    par.removeClass("checked");
else
    par.addClass("checked"); 

if ($('.tr').hasClass('checked')) 
{
    $('.finish').addClass('fixed');
} else {
    $('.finish').removeClass('fixed');
}

});
```

тогда попробуйте так, просто перенеся скобочку от `.click(function(){ ... });` в самый конец, и добавив Ваш второй скрипт в кучу к первому.

Comment: а как сюда еще добавить чтобы .fixed удалялся, когда нет .checked?

Comment: как-то так, наверно

Comment: спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```js
$(".input-checkbox").click(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      tr = $this.parent(".tr"),
      finish = $('.finish');
  
  if (!tr.hasClass("checked")){
    tr.addClass("checked");
    finish.addClass('fixed');
  } else {
    tr.removeClass("checked");
    finish.removeClass('fixed');
  }
});
```

```css
/* Для наглядности */

.checked {
  border: 1px solid red;
}


.finish {
  height: 20px;
}

.fixed {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tr"><input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="tr"><input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="tr"><input class="input-checkbox" type="checkbox"></div>
<div class="finish"></div>
```